# flink job is not distributed across machines

Tags: scala, batch-processing, apache-flink

I have small use case in Apache flink, which is, a batch processing system. I need to process a colletion of files. Processing of each file must be handled by one machine. I have this below code. All the time only one task slot is occupied, and the files are processed one after the other. I have 6 nodes (so 6 task managers) and configured 4 task slot in each node. So, i expect 24 files are processed at a time.

```scala
class MyMapPartitionFunction extends RichMapPartitionFunction[java.io.File, Int] {
  override def mapPartition(
      myfiles: java.lang.Iterable[java.io.File],
      out:org.apache.flink.util.Collector[Int])
    : Unit  =  {
    var temp = myfiles.iterator()
    while(temp.hasNext()){
      val fp1 = getRuntimeContext.getDistributedCache.getFile("hadoopRun.sh")
      val file = new File(temp.next().toURI)
      Process(
        "/bin/bash ./run.sh  " + argumentsList(3)+ "/" + file.getName + " " + argumentsList(7) + "/" + file.getName + ".csv",
        new File(fp1.getAbsoluteFile.getParent))
        .lines
        .foreach{println}
      out.collect(1)
    }
  }
}
```

I launched flink as ./bin/start-cluster.sh command and the web user interface shows it has 6 task managers, 24 task slots.

The folders contain about 49 files. When I create mapPartition on this collection, i expect 49 parallel processes are spanned. But then, in my infrastructure, they are all processed one after the other. This means that only one machine (one task manager) handles all the 49 filenames. What i want is, as configured 2 tasks per slots, I expect 24 files to be processed simultaneously.

Any pointers will surely help here.  I have these parameters in flink-conf.yaml file

```
jobmanager.heap.mb: 2048
taskmanager.heap.mb: 1024
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false
parallelism.default: 24
```

Thanks in advance. Can someone throw me light on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try to add **setParallelism(49)** after **mapPartition(new MyMapPartitionFunction())**. **env.fromCollection()** will create an operator with parallelism 1(even though you have configured the job parallelism to 24 in the flink-conf.yaml, because it uses **NonParallelInput** input format). Without setting the parallelism, the *partition map* operator will inherit its parallelism from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David described the problem is that `env.fromCollection(Iterable[T])` creates a `DataSource` with a non parallel `InputFormat`. Therefore, the `DataSource` is executed with a parallelism of `1`. The subsequent operators (`mapPartition`) inherit this parallelism from the source so that they can be chained (this saves us one network shuffle).

The way to solve this problem is to either explicitly rebalance the source `DataSet` via

```
env.fromCollection(folders).rebalance()
```

or to explicitly set the wished parallelism at the subsequent operator (`mapPartition`):

```
env.fromCollection(folders).mapPartition(...).setParallelism(49)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohrmann and David. rebalance() looked more clean and it worked too !!